# C++ - How to use a vector of reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, reference, binary-operators

I'm trying to refactor part of a pathfinding algorithm I had that used pointers to not use pointers. Unfortunately I'm not that knowledgable about references. I get the error: `Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::reference_wrapper<Tile>' and 'const std::__1::reference_wrapper<Tile>')`

I also have no idea what that means. My code is below, and I can gather that it comes from the line: `openList.erase(std::find(openList.begin(), openList.end(), current));` but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
bool TileMap::tilesBetween(Tile& p_start, Tile& p_end)
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Tile>> openList;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Tile>> closedList;

    openList.push_back(p_start);

    do
    {
        std::sort(openList.begin(), openList.end(), sortF());
        Tile& current = openList[0];
        closedList.push_back(current);
        openList.erase(std::find(openList.begin(), openList.end(), current));
        if(std::find(closedList.begin(), closedList.end(), p_end) != closedList.end())
        {
            return true;
        }

        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Tile>> adjacentTiles;
        if (current.m_coordinates.x > 0)
        {
            adjacentTiles.push_back(m_tiles[current.m_coordinates.y * m_width + (current.m_coordinates.x - 1)]);
        }
        if (current.m_coordinates.x < m_width)
        {
            adjacentTiles.push_back(m_tiles[current.m_coordinates.y * m_width + (current.m_coordinates.x + 1)]);
        }
        if (current.m_coordinates.y > 0)
        {
            adjacentTiles.push_back(m_tiles[(current.m_coordinates.y - 1) * m_width + current.m_coordinates.x]);
        }
        if (current.m_coordinates.y < m_height)
        {
            adjacentTiles.push_back(m_tiles[(current.m_coordinates.y + 1) * m_width + current.m_coordinates.x]);
        }

        for(auto t : adjacentTiles)
        {
            if(std::find(closedList.begin(), closedList.end(), t) != closedList.end())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(std::find(openList.begin(), openList.end(), t) == closedList.end())
            {
                openList.push_back(t);
            }
        }
    }
    while(!openList.empty());

    return false;
}
```

EDIT: posted `sortF`

```
struct sortF
{
    bool operator()(const Tile* p_a, const Tile* p_b) const
    {
        return p_a->f < p_b->f;
    }
};
```

UPDATE: As per the suggestion, I've changed the function to use pointers instead of references. It SEEMS to be working, but I have more to implement before it's finished.

```
bool TileMap::tilesBetween(Tile* p_start, Tile* p_end)
{
    std::vector<Tile*> openList;
    std::vector<Tile*> closedList;

    std::cout << p_start << ", ";

    openList.push_back(p_start);

    do
    {
        std::sort(openList.begin(), openList.end(), sortF());
        Tile* current = openList[0];
        closedList.push_back(current);
        openList.erase(std::find(openList.begin(), openList.end(), current));
        if(std::find(closedList.begin(), closedList.end(), p_end) != closedList.end())
        {
            return true;
        }

        std::vector<Tile*> adjacentTiles;
        if (current->m_coordinates.x > 0)
        {
            adjacentTiles.push_back(&m_tiles[current->m_coordinates.y * m_width + (current->m_coordinates.x - 1)]);
        }
        if (current->m_coordinates.x < m_width)
        {
            std::cout << &m_tiles[current->m_coordinates.y * m_width + (current->m_coordinates.x + 1)] << std::endl;
            adjacentTiles.push_back(&m_tiles[current->m_coordinates.y * m_width + (current->m_coordinates.x + 1)]);
        }
        if (current->m_coordinates.y > 0)
        {
            adjacentTiles.push_back(&m_tiles[(current->m_coordinates.y - 1) * m_width + current->m_coordinates.x]);
        }
        if (current->m_coordinates.y < m_height)
        {
            adjacentTiles.push_back(&m_tiles[(current->m_coordinates.y + 1) * m_width + current->m_coordinates.x]);
        }

        for(auto t : adjacentTiles)
        {
            if(std::find(closedList.begin(), closedList.end(), t) != closedList.end())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(std::find(openList.begin(), openList.end(), t) == openList.end())
            {
                openList.push_back(t);
            }
        }
    }
    while(!openList.empty());

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What line does the error come in?

Comment: @Barry - I think i've narrowed it to the `openList.erase(std::find(openList.begin(), openList.end(), current));` line.

Comment: Does `Tile` have `operator==` implemented?

Comment: No, it does not. I'm pretty new to C++ but i'll look that up.

Comment: What is `sortF`? Please post the definition of it.

Comment: @Barry - sortF is a struct that I use to sort the tiles based on a int value, `f`.

Comment: *I'm trying to refactor part of a pathfinding algorithm I had that used pointers to not use pointers* Why? There isn't anything wrong with using non-owning raw pointers, especially in cases like this where the use seems to be restricted to a single function.

Comment: @Praetorian - Would that require me storing the `Tile`s as pointers?

Comment: If you mean outside of `tilesBetween()`, then no, it shouldn't.

Comment: @Praetorian - I'll test that out then.

Comment: @EvanWard Seriously though, post `sortF`.

Comment: Posted `sortF` above.

Answer (score 6):

> I can gather that it comes from the line: openList.erase(std::find(openList.begin(), openList.end(), current)); but I'm not sure how to fix this.

`std::find` iterates over `std::reference_wrapper<Tile>` and not `Tile&` itself. Hence

```
    Tile& current = openList[0];
    openList.erase(std::find(openList.begin(), openList.end(), current));
```

is incorrect. Change this to

```
    openList.erase(std::find_if(openList.begin(), openList.end(), [&](const std::reference_wrapper<Tile> &i)
    {
        return i.get() == current;
    }));
```

`std::reference_wrapper::get` returns the underlying reference.

A simple, [working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/821890df6c1d8050) to demonstrate this

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct S
{
    int val;
    S(int i) : val(i) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::list<S> l = {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<S>> v(l.begin(), l.end());

    auto& x = l.front();
    v.erase(std::find_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [&](const std::reference_wrapper<S> &i)
    {
        return i.get().val == x.val;
    }));
    std::cout << v[0].get().val;
}
```

Comment: That works, but manually unwrapping the `reference_wrapper` is not required because it has an implicit conversion operator to `T&`. So you can avoid the lambda and use `find` as long as `S` is equality comparable - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dcd9b9164a93645

Comment: I tried without the manual unwrapping - lambda - in vain, but I'd implemented `operator==` as a member function, when I changed it to a external friend function it worked! Thanks to you I'd learned about the _[symmetric assumption](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=523)_ made in `std`'s generic algorithms.

Comment: [Symmetric Assumption](https://web.archive.org/web/20160711000208/http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=523) - Replacement for broken link.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
std::sort(openList.begin(), openList.end(), sortF());
```

Your `sortF` is an invalid comparison object. The `operator()` must look like this:

```
bool operator()(const Tile& lhs, const Tile& rhs) const
//              ^^^ ref ^^^      ^^^ ref ^^^
{
    return lhs.f < rhs.f;
}
```

Instead of:

```
bool operator()(const Tile* p_a, const Tile* p_b) const
//              ^^^ ptr ^^^      ^^^ ptr ^^^
```

You have a vector of `reference_wrapper<Tile>`, not a vector of `Tile*`.

Comment: Sorry, I was updating the whole function when I posted this so it didn't match. I did have it the way you suggested when it used references though.